# Acra lib package not found

Tags: android, package, acra

I have latest jar file of Acra-4.5.Orc-sources from this  [LINK](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadacra450rcsourcesjar.htm) all thing are completed but when i put it in lib folder and check to import not found anything but

when i extract jar file  all file are there

can anyone help me.. why this occure ...
is anything i am do wrong
sorry for my bad ENGLISH. and Thanks in advance..

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it looks like you have included the ACRA source library not the ACRA lib itself.

Second, ACRA-4.6.2 has been released. Recommend you use that instead.